# How do I send this backwards using z-index?

Tags: html, image, z-index

```
.line { 
text-align: center;
font-family:big;
font-size:60px;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 0 #FFFFFF, 1px 1px 0 #CCCCCC,
             2px -1px 0 #FFFFFF, 3px 0 0 #FFFFFF;
color:#2F1C0A;
background: #A89D7D url("brown.jpg") repeat-x right top;
border-bottom: solid #4E4A45 0.25em;
padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
position:relative;
z-index:-1;
}
```

I want to send it backwards to bring the image old.png (below is the code) forward:

```
body{
background: #AC9175 url("old.png") repeat-y right top;
background-size:5%;
}
```

Comment: pehaps this could be helpful -> **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context**

Comment: I don't think it can be done this way, it's not possible to place a child element lower than the parent itself.